# Is there a better way of defining a Screen Size in CSS for different devices

Tags: css

For example using a Media Query I can target certain viewports such as

```
@media (max-size: 480px;){
/* code here*/
}
```

but when I look up devices such as a iPad or a Samsung Galaxy Fold, I can only get screen resoultions, how do I target those? I am looking to to target all screen sizes on a Web App that I can

Comment: It would be a lot more easier to find a work around if you give your reason for getting the screen size

Comment: A website extends infinitely. Just set `height: 100%`. You should not design for devices. Just design for *any* and *all* sizes. The next device comes out tomorrow - why should you update your site for each individual device?

Comment: @fxtrot I'll add this, but basically to target all screen sizes on a Web App

Comment: A useful tip is to design using 4 to 6 major sizes (300px, 600px, 1000px, 1500px) then have the design slightly grow or shrink or have whitespace fill in the gaps (Flexbox and Grid are godsends for that sort of thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick to this rule 1500px+ - Desktop, 1500px- 1100px - Laptop, 1100px- 550px - Tablet, 550px- - Mobile.